# Can a group of joined tables be updated simultaneously in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a getter function that pulls a value from a series of joined tables like this:

```
SELECT
    foo
FROM
    my_table AS mt
LEFT JOIN my_other_table AS mot ON mt.pkey = mot.fkey
LEFT JOIN my_other_other_table AS moot ON mot.pkey = moot.fkey
WHERE
    mt.pkey = 0
```

I am wondering if there is a way to somehow convert this into a setter function that would allow me to update any part of this joined table, and have those changes propagate back to their original tables, i.e. something like this:

```
UPDATE
    my_table AS mt
    LEFT JOIN my_other_table AS mot ON mt.pkey = mot.fkey
    LEFT JOIN my_other_other_table AS moot ON mot.pkey = moot.fkey
SET
    mt.some_val = 0
    mot.some_other_val = 1
    moot.some_other_other_val = 2
WHERE
    mt.pkey = 0
```

I realize that the above code doesn't actually work, and I am fairly sure that this isn't actually possible, but I want to leave no stone unturned. Is there a way to do what I want to do? Or would it require a more complex plpgsql function?

Comment: Why is this important?

Comment: the top select could get multiple rows,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot in one statement, but you can create a transaction to do a all or nothing change:

```
begin;

UPDATE
    my_table AS mt
SET
    mt.some_val = 0
WHERE
    mt.pkey = 0;


UPDATE
    my_other_table AS mot 
SET
    mot.some_other_val = 1
FROM my_table AS mt
WHERE
    mt.pkey = mot.fkey AND mt.pkey = 0;

UPDATE
    my_other_other_table AS moot
SET
    moot.some_other_other_val = 2
FROM my_table AS mt
    INNER JOIN my_other_table AS mot ON mt.pkey = mot.fkey
WHERE
    mot.pkey = moot.fkey AND mt.pkey = 0;

COMMIT;
```